# How to group_by year in this type data in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I want to group this by Year:

```
[{"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>8}, "count"=>69605},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>7}, "count"=>60620},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>12}, "count"=>56026},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2014, "month"=>5}, "count"=>55067},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2014, "month"=>4}, "count"=>51313},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>11}, "count"=>48044},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2014, "month"=>8}, "count"=>43802},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2014, "month"=>1}, "count"=>40428},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2014, "month"=>3}, "count"=>39564},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>9}, "count"=>35682},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>10}, "count"=>34073},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2014, "month"=>2}, "count"=>32774},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2014, "month"=>6}, "count"=>30772},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2014, "month"=>9}, "count"=>17347},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2014, "month"=>7}, "count"=>5319},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>6}, "count"=>4468},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>5}, "count"=>2978},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>4}, "count"=>2498},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>3}, "count"=>360},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>1}, "count"=>112},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2012, "month"=>12}, "count"=>88},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>2}, "count"=>28},
 {"_id"=>{"year"=>2015, "month"=>11}, "count"=>1}]
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: please show how you tried to solve it?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Your_Array.group_by{|a| a["_id"]["year"]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You problem solved, check with the below solution

```
Your_array.group_by { |d| d['_id']['year'] }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Enumerable#reduce`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) comes to the rescue. Let’s say the data is stored in data variable:

```
data.reduce({}) { |memo, item| 
  (memo[item['_id']['year']] ||= []) << item; 
  memo 
}

# => {
#  2012 => [
#    [0] {
#        "_id" => {
#        "month" => 12,
#         "year" => 2012
#      },
#      "count" => 88
#    }
#  ],
#  2013 => [
#    [ 0] {
# ...
```

Is probably what you are looking for. Whether you want to yield restructured data, simply modify the callee.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would work for you:

```
array.group_by{|a| a["_id"]["year"]}.values
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Enumerable#group_by`.

```rb
array.group_by { |record| record['_id']['year'] }

#=> {2013=>
#  [{"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>8}, "count"=>69605},
#   ...
#   {"_id"=>{"year"=>2013, "month"=>2}, "count"=>28}],
# 2014=>
#  [{"_id"=>{"year"=>2014, "month"=>5}, "count"=>55067},
#   ...
#   {"_id"=>{"year"=>2014, "month"=>7}, "count"=>5319}],
# 2012=>[{"_id"=>{"year"=>2012, "month"=>12}, "count"=>88}],
# 2015=>[{"_id"=>{"year"=>2015, "month"=>11}, "count"=>1}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Enumerable#group_by`

```
grouped_array = array.group_by {|record| record["_id"]["year"]}
```

Use `Enumerable#sort_by` to sort records

```
sorted_array = grouped_array.sort_by{|year, records| year}
formated_hash = sorted_array.to_h
```

This will sort by ascending value of year. If you want to sort by descending values use `Array.reverse`

```
desc_sorted_array = sorted_array.reverse
formated_hash = desc_sorted_array.to_h
```

Comment: There is no point sorting a hash. Sort the keys and iterate over them to retrieve the values, or use `values_at` to retrieve them all at once.

Comment: That is good point, did not thought that way. I guess it is even faster then to use sort_by.

Comment: In this case, `sort_by` has no advantage. It'd be faster to use `sorted_keys = grouped_array.keys.sort` to get a list of the keys in order, and then use that list to extract the values using something like `grouped_array.values_at(*sorted_keys)` to retrieve them in order.

Comment: `sort` is faster than `sort_by` if the objects being sorted directly implement `<=>` and the value used isn't embedded, like basic objects such as Integers and Strings. Once you move to more complicated objects where you have to use getters or methods to compute the value used to sort, then `sort_by` is much faster.